# Restructuring Game on

Tags: discussion, game-on

Game On! has been running into some issues. The turn out has been low, and I've received several request to restructure the current system.

The main issue raised is that users dislike the large number of games currently on the list. Due to this we wind up playing a game once, and not coming back to it again until 5 months later. So it's time to look at a new system, and find out any other issues users have.

First, this is my proposal for a new system:

We divide games into two categories: Core and non-core. The core games would be a  small list of  games (I'm thinking either 3 or 4), and the non-core a much larger list of games. We would play one of the core games for 2 weeks, and then we would play a non-core game for a week, then move onto the next core game for 2 weeks, then onto another non-core for a week, et cetera...

The main criteria I'll be looking for in the core games are:

- Free
- Popular
- Low-mid level computer spec. requirements
- People can easily drop in and out of the game as they please

The non-core games could essentially be anything else, so long it receives enough positive feedback from the community

A few games which come to mind as possible core  games are:

- Team Fortress 2:
   + Free
   + Popular
   + Mid Level spec. requirements
   + Supports a larger number of people
   - Requires a large number of people to play
- Minecraft:
  + Popular
  + Low Spec requirements
  + Mods can give a variety of game types outside of Vanilla minecraft (Race for wool is one example)
  - Not Free
- Xonotic:
  + low-mid level spec requirements
  + Free
  + Can be played on any OS
  + Supports a larger number of players, but is enjoyable with any number of players
  \? Uncertain of popularity

Time to hear some thoughts from the community. Any suggestions for a new structure? Any issues with my proposal? Any suggestions for deciding core games? et cetera.

Comment: Even then, you're only playing each "core" game for one cycle every 3 months. That seems a bit sparse.

Comment: @StrixVaria I'm aware this system isn't perfect, which is why I made the meta. So that this can be improved, and so other users can suggest different (Hopefully better) methods.

Comment: I'll think about it. It's hard to cater to a wide variety of interests at once.

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about 2 of the 3 core games being FPSs.  Is there a free RTS we can play? (Does anyone around here like RTS except me?)

Comment: Those are just example games so users have an idea of what I'm looking for in Core Games.

Comment: @StrixVaria I know. I'm hoping we can come up with a system that satisfies as much of the community as possible.

Comment: Is the community large enough to support concurrent gaming? If so, perhaps two or three different genre games could be selected for each rotation. e.g. an fps and an rts

Comment: Don't forget Tankball 2.

Answer (score 3):

How about something simpler:

- Minecraft friday
- Team Fortress 2 saturday
- Every-week-something-different sunday

Comment: What about Xonotic?

Comment: @GnomeSlice Feel free to suggest a different system

Comment: @GnomeSlice Every once in a while on a sunday.

Comment: Xonotic is free, where Minecraft is not.

Comment: @GnomeSlice A lot of us have Minecraft, but we have no Xonotic regular on chat, or Xonotic questions on the site. Pardon me if I put Minecraft before Xonotic.

Comment: I really like this system myself.

Comment: It's been 10 days.  The current schedule ends in 2-ish weeks.  How many upvotes does this answer need before we apply it and go update the schedule accordingly?